# Read a larger file-A and retrieve related strings in 2nd file and create an output

Tags: text-processing, grep

I'm running a for loop against two larger files (1.6 to 47 million entries) and each line grep is taking to much time. was wondering if there's another faster solution that I can use here. Basically, I need to read FILE-A for each line and grep it against FILE-B.csv and create a resulting output.

```
FILE-A: (1.6 million IDs)
FILE-B.csv: (47 million IDs & Other Attributes)

for UID in $(cat FILE-A); do
  cat FILE-B.csv | grep $i >> OUTPUT-FILE.csv
done
```

Comment: GNU `grep` allows you to do this: `grep -F -f file-A file-B`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -F -f FILE-A FILE-B.csv
```

`-f` specifies the file from which to obtain patterns.  `-F` specifies the pattern as a fixed-string, separated by newlines.

With regard to you original code thought, piping `cat` into `grep` is a useless waste of resources.  `grep` can read a file directly.